# Manga where they didn't know they went to hell

Tags: story-identification, manga

They didn't realize they actually went to another dimension, which is Hell, because it still looked like their town, and they are still alive(?). In the middle of the plot they had to avoid getting caught up with Hell's various punishments. Then at the end they had to repent, say sorry, and honor their mother, father, or something. It also looks like an old art style and gore-y.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found it!

[*Hotarubi no Tomoru Koro ni*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/95059/Hotarubi_no_Tomoru_Koro_ni)

The summary started with family reunion because the grandma died in their hometown, then they didn't realize they have gone to hell overnight. There's a female character who knows about the place and guided the family to how to survive from the monsters.

Comment: Congratulations! You can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, although as a self-answer, it won't let you do that until tomorrow.